# shell saves ip address that you ping?

Tags: bash, command-line, command-history

I was once shown a shortcut that I can't recall/ find. After pinging an ip, then attempting to ssh into it - the ip was saved into to a variable automagically.

Something like:

```
    ping 10.1.23.4
    ...
    ssh root@$!
```

and the ip was replicated in the second line replacing $! without further ado.

So does this ring a bell as to what the actual syntax is? Or was this some special configuration? I believe this was running centos if that is related.
tia

Comment: You have your bang and your dollar sign transposed: try `ssh root@!$`... See 'history expansion' in `man bash` for the details.

Comment: note: zsh does this automagically, with tab-completion.

Comment: I suggest to look the book: Pro Bash Programming Scripting. It is a great source of Bash tips!

Answer (score 3):

This is a bashism -- bash being the default shell language in CentOS. (Csh has something similar.) Check out the part about [History Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction) in the manual; probably you are interested in `!*`, which is "all the arguments to the previous command", or `!^`, which will give you the first one, or `!$`, which will give you the last.

Note that these *aren't* variables. They're expanded and replaced with the replacement value in the history.

Comment: Or better yet; ssh root@!$... – jasonwryan 6 mins ago -> in comment above

Comment: Yes, although I'm mildly disturbed that you have a system into which you can ssh as root. :)

Comment: `bash` (and `zsh`) copied it from `csh` (which invented it over 10 years earlier), so I'd rather call it a cshism. POSIX shells have `$_` for that.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Well, except the shell in question _is_ bash. I guess we could call it a csh-ism that bash borrowed — the bash documentation readily says so.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, if you are using bash in emacs editing mode (the default), then you can do:

`$ ping x.x.x.x`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd>

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> will delete the last word (the IP address), putting it in the **kill ring**, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd> will paste the contents of the kill ring.

You can then run any number of commands, and then at the point you need the IP again just
reuse <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd>

`$ ssh root@`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd>

Note that issuing any kill related functions on a new command line, will replace the contents of the kill ring:

`$ ping x.x.x.x`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd>

`$ touch /tmp/example.file`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd>

`$ ssh root@`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd>

will result in:

`$ ssh root@/tmp/example.file`